# Is there a way to fill a collection using a LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iteration

One of the great things about LINQ is that allows you to get information that's related to a collection without having to manually write code to iterate through the collection.  **Is there a way to use LINQ to populate a collection, thus avoiding the need to write a loop?**

---

For example, let's say I have the following code which works with a range of numbers from one to ten:

```
public static void LinqTest()
{
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)     //  <==== I'm having to use a for loop
        intList.Add(i);               //        here to populate the List.
    int intSum = intList.Sum();
    int intSumOdds = intList.Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Sum();
    double intAverage = intList.Average();
    Console.WriteLine("Sum is {0}\tSum of Odds is {1}\tAverage is {2}", 
        intSum, intSumOdds, intAverage);
}
```

LINQ is already replacing the `for` loops that would be required to **retrieve** information about the data.  I'm curious as if LINQ could be used to replace the `for` loop that **populates** data. Is there a way to use LINQ to replace the following two lines of code?

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        intList.Add(i);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others have said, you can use `Enumerable.Range(int, int)` to generate a sequence of integers returned as `IEnumerable<int>`.

And while you can convert the result to a `List<int>` in the various ways that have been suggested already, you should only do that if you actually need a `List<T>`.

In this case, there is no need to do so. Your function could be rewritten as follows:

```
IEnumerable<int> intList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
int intSum = intList.Sum();
int intSumOdds = intList.Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Sum();
double intAverage = intList.Average();
```

This is more efficient since the sequence returned by `Enumerable.Range` is generated "lazily" as it is enumerated. On the other hand, when the sequence is converted to a `List<int>` then all of the values must be held in memory at once.

Comment: +1 for avoiding using List<int> in favour of IEnumerable<int>

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't fill an existing list with LINQ; you'd create an Enumerable and then convert it to a list. In this case, it's as simple as

```
IList<int> intList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 Nice, but you are off by one if you want to match the example in the question. int i = 1; i <= 10; i++

Comment: +1 good answer. little remark: The runtime does exactly the same, maybe a little bit faster because it's natively compiled. Well, with the JIT-compiler that's not even sure.

Comment: The `Enumerable` class is part of `System.Linq`, so does that mean we're still using LINQ?

Comment: Well, LINQ is really two things: a set of methods for generating and working with enumerables, and a special syntax for using those methods. In this case, we're using the former but not the latter. I think you probably do `(from Enumerable.Range(1, 10)).ToList()` if you want to use the special syntax, though I don't see the advantage.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for in the specific case is `Enumerable.Range()`. From there, if you want to you can filter the list by using `Where`s and such. For instance, if i wanted all the numbers from whose power of two is below 100 i'd do something like `Enumerable.Range(1,100).Where(i => i * i < 100)`. This is very common in functional languages like Haskell where something similar is this: `filter (\i -> i * i < 100) [1..100]`

A specific example to replace your function:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,10).Where(x => x%2 == 1).Sum();
//add separate sum and averages here
```

Comment: That makes sense. I wasn't sure at the time if Sum needed a bunch of params if it wasn't a list though.

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` has a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>` as a parameter. You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) to generate the numbers.

```
List<int> values = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
```

If you want to add the values to a previously constructed `List<T>`, you can use `List<T>.AddRange` in the same way:

```
values.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
```