# Using LINQ with conditions

Tags: c#, linq

Given a class

```
public class data
{
   public string x;
   public double y;
}

List<data> myList = new List<data>();
```

The list is then populated with data either with string "odd", string "even" with the respective number.

how would I get the sum of all the x = "odd" using linq

This is will be basic to most, please pardon my ignorance...

Comment: Can we cool it with the closing hate?  This is a reasonable question.

Comment: I'm intrigued. Surely "odd" and "even" can only be used to describe integer values?

Comment: @DaveSwersky No research effort. Searching `linq sum odd` turned up [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032411/is-there-a-way-to-fill-a-collection-using-a-linq-expression), which doesn't exactly make this a duplicate, but definitely turns up code snippets that do exactly what he wants. I'd consider it a reasonable question if documentation/a few seconds of Googling didn't help.

Comment: Thanks Guys!!!! googling didnt bring up simple answers

Comment: @tnw "No research effort" is a reason to downvote. Not a close reason and the [General Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86043/148672) close reason was declined.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're asking a basic question, start here: [Standard Query Operators Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397896.aspx). Everything under "Related Sections" is worth checking out.

The references (with examples) for the functions used in the answers are here: [Where(predicate)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx), [Sum(selector)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use `Where` to get only `data` with `x == "odd"` and use `Sum` to get the sum.

```
double sumOdd = myList.Where(d => d.x == "odd").Sum(d => d.y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 List<data> myList = new List<data>();
 var odd = myList.Where(p => p.x == "odd").Sum(z => z.y) ;
 var even = myList.Where(p => p.x == "even").Sum(z => z.y) ;
```

Comment: I think Where won't necessarily return a List<>, just an IEnumerable. To save on declaration length, I would just write `var oddList`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var sum = myList.Where(d => d.x == "odd").Sum(d => d.y);
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but you don't *have* to use `Where` and `Sum` :)

```
dataList.Aggregate(0, (result, next) => result + (next.x == "odd" ? next.y : 0.0));
```