# Creating a List of given size, all initialized to some value, in C#

Tags: c#, list

Is there a compact manner in which the following can be done?

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   a.Add(0);
```

i.e., creating a list of n elements, all of value 0.

Comment: That's pretty compact. And maybe yes, there's a "smooth" or fancy way to do it, but what you've written is clear to even novice developers. Good enough!

Comment: So, maybe a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032411/is-there-a-way-to-fill-a-collection-using-a-linq-expression

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-initializing C# lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104457/auto-initializing-c-sharp-lists)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill List<int> with default values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363940/fill-listint-with-default-values)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Enumberable.Repeat` would be the shortest method I can think of:

```
var a = Enumerable.Repeat(0, n).ToList();
```

Comment: It's worth calling out that the `Enumerable` methods have the benefit of being lazy if you don't invoke the `ToList` up front.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`Enumerable.Repeat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) generator:

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Repeat(0, n));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> x = Enumerable.Repeat(value, count).ToList();
```